# Apache won't stop starting

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd

> /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6906  0.0  0.1 187032  5448 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6907  0.0  0.1 187032  5448 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6908  0.0  0.1 187032  5448 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6909  0.0  0.1 187032  5448 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6910  0.7  0.1 187712  7024 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6911  1.7  0.1 188216  7036 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6912  0.5  0.1 187712  7020 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6913  0.4  0.1 188216  7028 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6914  0.8  0.1 188216  7028 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6915  0.7  0.1 188216  7028 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6916  0.5  0.1 188216  7028 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6917  0.2  0.1 188216  7024 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6918  0.5  0.1 188216  7028 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6919  0.8  0.1 188216  7028 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6920  0.5  0.1 187712  7020 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6921  0.8  0.1 187712  7020 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6922  1.0  0.1 188216  7024 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6923  0.6  0.1 188216  7024 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6924  1.5  0.1 187712  7020 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6925  0.1  0.1 187712  7012 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6926  1.2  0.1 187712  7016 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6927  0.5  0.1 188216  7028 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL nobody    6928  1.2  0.1 187712  7024 ?        S    13:20   0:00
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
>   -DSSL

I have 258 of these running. I stopped httpd, and it went back down to 0. I started it back up, and it quickly went back to 258. I have never seen this before. Anyone know what's wrong?

I'm running CentOS5.5 with Apache2.2 on cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

You have many workers configured, I am not sure which module you are using but the relevant section is

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxClients         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

You could check it and see how many servers you have. I presume it is 250+.

Answer (score 0):

While not the best way, you could brute-force it with
chmod -x /path/to/apachebinary